# Integrity Error with Django 2.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-unittest

I try to update one of my projects to Django 2.1.

It is perfectly working with Django 2.0.7 and after the update to Django 2.1 I obtain the following error while trying to launch the unit tests:

```
python manage.py test

Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\gitpro~1\feedcr~1.io\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\gitpro~1\feedcr~1.io\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 296, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_permission.content_type_id, auth_permission.codename
```

Any idea on what could be the cause, I tried to give a look to the Changelog and it didn't really help...

Changelog: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/

Comment: Did you create and apply migrations?

Comment: Absolutely, but this shoulddn't be a problem, django creates a new sqlite database for test and automatically applies the migations. As I said, the **exact** same process leads to an error with Django 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was induced by the application: `django-admin-view-permission` which is not necessary anymore with Django 2.1.

Related Github Issues: https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-view-permission/issues/55